# Set Bootstrap Input Group Labels background-color to an #rgb value

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The example code shows an input field with an **Input Group Label**. The background color of the Input Group Label is already set by default.

I need to modify this to an own **RGB** value. For example: `#646464`

I tried to modify the **background color** of the `<span>` and the `<div>` as you can see in the CSS code, but none of them solved my problem. The background color of the Input Group Label remains the same.

```css
.myDivClass {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.mySpanClass {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container mt-3">
    <form>
      <label for="demo">Write your email here:</label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="demo" name="email">
        <div class="input-group-append myDivClass">
          <span class="input-group-text mySpanClass">@example.com</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also shows the code which you tried

Comment: did you add your class in the element which you want to change the background color ?

Comment: @Babar I updated my question with the background color example code. As I can see, it is still not working. I tried to set the color based on both element class.

Comment: But you haven't added .myDivClass and .mySpanClass to the corresponding tags in html.

Comment: @questionMark please check the answer and try it that way. Thanks

Comment: @s.kuznetsov True, I realized and updated my example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```css
.myDivClass {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

span.mySpanClass {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container mt-3">
    <form>
      <label for="demo">Write your email here:</label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="demo" name="email">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="mySpanClass input-group-text">@example.com</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Do you have any explanation why does it matters that "span" states before ".myDivClass"?

Comment: @questionMark you need to add your custom styling after the boostrap.css file.
you can see the example here https://codepen.io/babarkhan/pen/ZELdZoL